# Determining how much of the network bandwith is utilized during/after a jmeter test

Tags: http, jmeter, bandwidth, throughput, bandwidth-throttling

I want to understand how to determine whether my internet connection is a bottleneck or not during a jmeter stress test.

Here is a bit of background for my problem:

I made a stress test with a 2 hours duration, with 2000 threads ramped up over the whole 2 hours duration hoping to find the upper limit of the server, but I am thinking that maybe I hit some other limit and not the server's, as it's not shutting down, aka not responding with 4xx or 5xx error codes. I can only see in the report that the transactions per second go fairly quickly to 580, but they then will not go above.

When I run the stress test against one server endpoint and the load keeps increasing, I need to be connected to a VPN to have access to that endpoint.

Most of the stress test runs I tried, behave like this:
[image]

Although, the number of threads increases, like this:
[image]

And I only have Non-HTTP error response codes which are not reflected in the server logs, aka the server reports no 4xx or 5xx error codes:
[image]

The server will not go over 580 TPS, but it will not throw errors either:
[image]

As per [this site](https://www.speedtest.net/), my internet connection (via cable or wifi, I see no major difference) has 1ms ping, 400-420 Mbps download capacity and around 250 Mbps upload capacity - granted, this is calculated with some server selected by them, located relatively near to my location.

How can I know how much of that "pipe" capacity is being used so that I can say with certainty that my internet connection is not a bottleneck?
Can the VPN be a bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options like:

1. [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) chart which is a part of JMeter's HTML Reporting Dashboard

   [image]
2. [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput/) chart from [JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)s project

   [image]
3. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) which provides [complete Network IO metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent/blob/master/README.md#network-io-metrics)

   [image]
4. Your operating system should provide built-in applications for network monitoring